# How to customize Bean Validations ConstraintViolationException?

Tags: java, spring, rest, bean-validation

I want to validate the `@RequestBody` of an endpoint in my Spring `@RestController`. So I created a method like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = ...)
public ResponseEntity<...> myPostMethod(@RequestBody MyBean myBean) throws Exception {
```

`MyBean` is decorated with a custom `@Constraint` and its respective validation logic is implemented on a `ConstraintValidator` class that I created. This validator has a method like:

```
@Override
public boolean isValid(MyBean value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
```

That's where all the validation logic takes place. When it fails, `isValid` returns `false` and I can use that `context` param to build a validation error message the way I want. In addition, `myPostMethod` also fails with an automatic (because I do not throw it myself) `MethodArgumentNotValidException` that I'm going to capture on a global handler in order to render a generic `ResponseEntity`. It all works as expected. **The question is:** how do I customize not only the validation error message, but also the whole `ConstraintViolationException`? I want to provide more data (from my business domain) inside the exception to render in the response body json.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer:

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.4/api/org/hibernate/validator/constraintvalidation/HibernateConstraintValidatorContext.html#withDynamicPayload-java.lang.Object-

```
public boolean isValid(MyBean value, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
    HibernateConstraintValidatorContext context = constraintValidatorContext.unwrap(HibernateConstraintValidatorContext.class);

    // (...)

    context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate( "{foo}" )
        .withDynamicPayload(anyAdditionalInfo)
        .addConstraintViolation();

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that the additional parameter you wanted to pass is called `myParam`.

First, declare an accessor for that parameter in your Constraint interface;

```
public @interface MyConstraint {

    String message();

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    String myParam() default "some.value";
}
```

Then in the `ConstraintValidator`, you could access these params like:

```
public class MyValidator implements ConstraintValidator<MyConstraint, String> {

    private String myParam;


    @Override
    public void initialize(OpcoConstraint parameters) {
        code = parameters.myParam();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {

        HibernateConstraintValidatorContext hibernateContext = context.unwrap(
                HibernateConstraintValidatorContext.class
        );

        // you can pass any object as the payload
        hibernateContext.withDynamicPayload(Map.of("myParam", myParam));
    }
}
```

If you catch the `ConstraintViolationException` from an exception handler and want to access the parameter from the Exception itself:

To retrieve `ConstraintViolation` (s) out of `ConstraintViolationException` use:

```
constraintViolationException.getConstraintViolations();
```

Then to retrieve the dynamic payload out of a `ConstraintViolation`:

```
(Map) ((ConstraintViolationImpl) constraintViolation).getDynamicPayload(Map.class))
```